# how to make json.loads() read a json string with the column names as the first element

Tags: python, json

I am serializing a datatable from a http get and for performance reasons would prefer to serialize it in a Names, Values structure, so that the first element contains the column names, can json.loads deal with this, if not is there another json parser that will?

```
{
    "Names" : ["summaryDate","count"],
    "Values" : [["2020-01-15T00:00:00",10],["2020-01-16T00:00:00",12],["2020-01-17T00:00:00",16]]
}
```

(this reduces the size to 20% of a standard JSON stream with the field names repeated for each 'row')

Comment: What is it you're asking? If you just want to ask, if Python can load this JSON file, why don't you just try it?

Comment: `json.load()` just takes a json string and __de__serialize it to it's Python equivalent - so If your issue is with what the json string looks like, you have to fix it at the source (the serialization process itself).

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle yes, I DID try it, and NO, it doesn't work, hence my question I am asking how to do it, sorry if my question wasn't exact enough for you - json.loads() doesn't work, as was helpfully pointed out by bruno... However as I state in the final sentence, the stream is 4x the size if every object contains the field names, hence the question as to whether it is possible. the web service supports this method of serialisation which seems sensible for a datatable response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some digging and found ijson.
It lets you iterate over a json file and access its objects.
you can build you data structur like this(i was lazy and used pd):

```
import ijson
import pandas as pd
f= open("testjson.txt",'r')
f2= open("testjson.txt",'r')
names=[]
values=[]
names = ijson.items(f, 'Names.item')
values = ijson.items(f2, 'Values.item')

pd.DataFrame(values,columns=list(names))
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution - it has inspired me to simplify it slightly to:

data = json.loads(json_stream)
df = pd.DataFrame(data["Values"], columns=list(data["Names"]))

Answer (score 0):

you can load it in a dictionnary with json , and then apply this formula to obtain the dictionnary you want:

```
dic = {
"Names" : ["summaryDate","count"],
"Values" : [["2020-01-15T00:00:00",10],["2020-01-16T00:00:00",12],["2020-01-17T00:00:00",16]]
}
d=[ {'SummaryDate':summaryDate,'count':count} for summaryDate,count in dic['Values']]
```